# How do I split a record of text into text file in C++

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a simple file manipulating project where I need to append a new text on a single line, so, to visualize that suppose I have a text file called `main.txt` and in that file it contains a row of text that looks like this:

```
[AB]
1
2
```

Now that lets say I want to add another text: `[CB]` & `4,5`, then I want the updated file to looked like this:

```
[AB] [CB]

1     4

2     5
```

But turns out it looked like this instead:

```
[Ab]
1
2
    [CB]
    4
    5
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::ofstream file("C:\users\USER\Documents\CPPPRoject\nice.txt",std::ios::out|std::ios::app);
    file << "\t" << "[CB]" << "\n";
    file << "\t" << 4 << "\n";
    file << "\t" << 5 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes of course you're append to the file. it just like you open it in notepad, move to end, and type those by hand.

Comment: @appleapple That will destroys the whole point of my project. I need to do it manually by programming.

Comment: @ Pythonic User , I mean, it does not work because it does not work by hand either. append in the end doesn't magically interlace the content.

Comment: btw, most filesystem (or, their exposed file API) doesn't support insert data in middle of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // we have only 1 column in this example and also we have only 2 rows of data
    int columnCount = 1, dataRows = 2;
    string newColumnName;
    int data1, data2;
    cout << "enter the column name: ";
    cin >> newColumnName;
    // getting the new datas based on the amount of the rows
    int *data = new int[dataRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataRows; i++)
        cin >> data[i];
    // opening the orginal.txt and pasting it into copy.txt with new data
    fstream original, copy;
    original.open("original.txt", ios::in);
    copy.open("copy.txt", ios::out);
    // copy & paste the columns
    string inStr;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        original >> inStr;
        copy << inStr << " ";
    }
    copy << newColumnName << "\n";
    // copy past the columns
    int inData;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            original >> inData;
            copy << inData << "    ";
        }
        copy << data[i] << "\n";
    }
    original.close();
    copy.close();
    // deleting the original and renaming the copy.txt
    remove("original.txt");
    rename("copy.txt", "original.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

this is a simple code to add a column to the text file which only have 1 column of data , for doing it to larger file you can adjust `columnCount` and `dataRows` .

**sample test of code :**
*original.txt before running the code*

```
[AB]
5
6
```

*program inputs ( column name and new data to insert)*

```
enter the column name: [CD]
1 2
```

*original.txt file after execution of the code*

```
[AB] [CD]
5    1
6    2
```

Comment: I'm definitely interested for the code snippets, can you provide your solution?

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer.

Comment: @PythonicUser well I'm going to make a copy of the original text file then I will delete the original file with the correct name. I will start to copy from the clone into the original one but I will insert new data at the end of the lines so it will be like you are adding a new column. I used this method on one of my college projects when I need to insert a new column into my data and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MohamadrezaHabibzade usually it's done by write to a new file, then replace the original (probably with [ReplaceFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-replacefilea)), this make it 1 less copy than what you describe.

Comment: @PythonicUser answer has been edited

Comment: @appleapple yeah, I used your advice, remove() to remove the original and rename for renaming the copy to the original.

Comment: Ok, so your code works just like what I desired for but then there this random integers printed on the text file. For first column input I inserted: `Age` and for rows I inserted `2` & `4`, but then two random numbers generated: `2051645986` and `2051645986` on the left side of both rows, why?

Comment: @PythonicUser well do u have only 1 column in original.txt ? if you have more columns you had to adjust columnCount ; otherwise, I have no idea what's going on...